# Error Invalid Scopes: offline_access, publish_stream, when I try to connect with Facebook API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-graph-api-v2.3

I got this error when I try to connect with Facebook API

> **Invalid Scopes: offline_access, publish_stream. This message is only shown to developers. Users of your app will ignore these permissions if present. Please read the documentation for valid permissions at: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/Facebook-login/permissions**

Before I can connect my website with my Facebook account without problem and today I got the error above, the app is in my Facebook account
when I use other Facebook account users of my app I can connect to my website without problem.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the relevant parts of your code? Also, please format the error message as a quote (by putting it on a new line starting with `>`) so that it's clear what is question and what is exception. Having it emboldened makes it **harder to read**.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

The permissions `offline_access` and `publish_stream` are deprecated, thus cannot be requested anymore.

`publish_stream` can be replaced by `publish_actions`, `offline_access` is gone.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.4#reference
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

Comment: Waw thanks so much that's work !! but why I didn't have this probleme before ?

Comment: Because Graph API v1.0 was deprecated on April 30th 2015.

Comment: Please tell me where I need to replace it.... I am unable to login in facebook android app

Answer (score 11):

Just use `publish_actions` instead of `publish_stream`.

Comment: Please tell me how to replace it and where? I really do not find any solution yet... I am unable to login into facebook from my app

Comment: @NikW in your Facebook Login API call - it depends on language. For example in JavaScript:


`FB.login(function(response) {
   // handle the response
 }, {
   scope: 'publish_actions', 
   return_scopes: true
 });`

Comment: i m asking for user_friends and user_gender which is listed in FB permissions but getting same error. Can you please suggest it?

Answer (score 0):

In the below form you can see the value having the `publish_stream` and `offline_access` parameters which is [deprecated](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.3#reference) as said above by Tobi.

```
<form th:action="@{/signin/facebook}" method="POST">
        <button type="submit">Sign in with Facebook</button>
        <input type="hidden" name="scope" value="email,publish_stream,offline_access" />
</form>
```

so remove those two parameters and change the  to,

```
<input type="hidden" name="scope" value="email,publish_actions" />
```