# Facebook Invalid Scope error

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have created an app of V2.3 with rails app. It was working fine before April 30th. 
Now I am getting this error :

> Invalid Scopes: offline_access, publish_stream, create_event,
>   friends_events. This message is only shown to developers. Users of
>   your app will ignore these permissions if present. Please read the
>   documentation for valid permissions at:
>   https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions

I have even given permission to the app via Graph API Explorer. Still I am not able to resolve it.

Similar Question : [Error Invalid Scopes: offline_access, publish_stream, when I try to connect with Facebook API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30074899/error-invalid-scopes-offline-access-publish-stream-when-i-try-to-connect-wi/30093549#30093549)

Adding Comments - This didn't solve my problem. I have tried this solution.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error Invalid Scopes: offline\_access, publish\_stream... when i try to connect with Facebook API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30074899/error-invalid-scopes-offline-access-publish-stream-when-i-try-to-connect-wi)

Answer (score 5):

All those permissions don´t exist anymore, some of them are deprecated since many years - and v1.0 was removed at April 30th, 2015 - meaning, a lot of deprecated stuff is not working anymore. Check out the changelog for more information: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

I suggest not using old online tutorials to copy code from, always use the Facebook docs first.

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand why you have to post the question, as you linked the one already answered yesterday.

You have to remove the repsective permissions from the `scope` parameter of the Login URL.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/#logindialog
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/v2.3#login

> `scope`: A comma separated list of Permissions to request from the person using your app.

You **CANNOT** use these permissions after April 30th 2015.

Comment: Because that link didn't solve my problem. & I was unable to comment on those already commented. My question was removed from that post & was asked to create a new one.

Comment: What exactly did you do to solve it? If you's have removed the permissions from the scope, the error would be gone! Simple as that. Read the docs.

Comment: In App Details --> Configure App Center Permissions, removed all permissions. And also cleared the access token permissions from Graph API Explorer. Is there any problem if the app is not live ?

Comment: That's nonsense. You need to set the `scope` of the login URL in the code of your app, as I said twice before.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30096263/how-to-remove-permissions-offline-access-and-publish-stream-in-scope-variable

Comment: The above link has different solution as he is using HybridAuth which is a PHP Library. As I am using Koala in ROR, I am looking at the scope permissions as you said.

Comment: You should have stated that in your question, as well as your Koala version

Comment: Look at https://github.com/arsduo/koala/wiki/OAuth#oauth-urls-and-tokens You should be able to define the scope / permissions with `@oauth.url_for_oauth_code(:permissions => "permission1,permission2,permission3")`

Comment: Ya, I should have mentioned that. Actually prior to April 30th, it was the same issue with permissions. I fixed it with the solution in GraphAPI Explorer. I selected my app --> Then get Access Token. Where we can select all the permissions which we wanted. It solved the issue. There was no code change for that.

Comment: I can't believe this would work. The Access Token will expire, and this wouldn't change anything for the login. Where Koala is involved then I can't understand. What did you do then with the Access Token?

Comment: So, the generated access token has all the permissions we wanted from the GraphAPI Explorer. Through Koala, we get that token & save it into our database. So whenever the person logs out, we take the fresh access token & save it and show data accordingly.

Comment: I don't understand this, but well.