# How to remove permissions offline_access and publish_stream in scope variable

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, drupal, drupal-7, hybridauth

I have error when I want login drupal 7 with facebook account and I use module hybridauth.

like this:

> Invalid Scopes: offline_access, publish_stream. This message is only shown to developers. Users of your app will ignore these permissions if present. Please read the documentation for valid permissions at: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions

From same question I found the answer and it is to remove permissions offline_access and publish_stream in scope variable but I don't understand how to do that?

anyone can help me?

Comment: hi. i having the same issue.. did find the solution??

Comment: go to Configuration -> HybridAuth -> klik settings on facebook -> klik Advanced Setting on right menu -> you can uncheck offline_access and publish_stream.

with my bad english I hope you know what I mean hehehe

Answer (score 0):

The permissions offline_access and publish_stream are deprecated, thus cannot be requested anymore.

publish_stream can be replaced by publish_actions, offline_access is gone.

See

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.4#reference
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

Answer (score 0):

If you have following Url request while login with Facebook authentication (1). Then you have to remove last parameter you are sending and try following url (2) request hope it will works.

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=113006002193070&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fyougagged.com%2Findex&scope=email%2C+offline_access (1)
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=113006002193070&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fyougagged.com%2Findex (2)
```