# Integrate facebook login in cordova app

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app

I am facing below error while doing facebook login into my app.

Invalid Scopes: offline_access, publish_stream. This message is only shown to developers. Users of your app will ignore these permissions if present. Please read the documentation for valid permissions at: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/Facebook-login/permissions

I checked for many answers they told change the permission, but into my fb developer there is no option to set any kind of permission, Please help me where can I found permission option to set.

Comment: What permissions your app asks for is usually specified in the code ...

Comment: Somewhere in your code (or the libraries you're using - if so, you're using very outdated ones) there's code to request this. Use your IDE to search the entire directory for `offline_access` and find out where it's being requested. Alternatively, do nothing - as the message says, the invalid permissions will just be ignored - you only see the message because you're an admin of the app.

Comment: please read this one : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30074899/error-invalid-scopes-offline-access-publish-stream-when-i-try-to-connect-with  and this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30094382/facebook-invalid-scope-error

Comment: I don't think that problem inside the library Because same library working fine with other facebook developer account app, which is not related to my project, Once  I created my app id into my developer account it saying the Invalid scope error i posted.