# Error Social Auth 4.4:: Invalid Scopes: publish_stream.

Tags: android, facebook, social-authentication

I got this error when i try to connect with [SOCIAL AUTH](http://www.3pillarglobal.com/insights/part-1-using-socialauth-to-integrate-facebook-api-in-android) 4.4 TO INTEGRATE FACEBOOK API IN ANDROID.

Few days back everything is working fine and i am able to post the data to Facebook from my application.

Now i am getting this error while trying to access the Facebook from my application.

> Invalid Scopes: offline_access, publish_stream. This message is only
>   shown to developers. Users of your app will ignore these permissions
>   if present. Please read the documentation for valid permissions at:
>   https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions

After reading the documentations i came to know that , The permissions offline_access and publish_stream are deprecated, thus cannot be requested anymore.

So i replaced my properties file according to the documentation.

publish_stream can be replaced by publish_actions, offline_access is gone.

Like Below:::

```
#facebook
graph.facebook.com.consumer_key = XXXXXXXXXXXXX
graph.facebook.com.consumer_secret = XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
graph.facebook.com.custom_permission = publish_actions,email,user_birthday,user_location
```

Still i am getting the same issue. Where exactly i am missing..

Comment: you can´t get the same error if you removed those permissions. are you sure you don´t get a different error message?

Comment: @yes luschn i am getting the same error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Facebook changed too many internal settings recently it is better to use Facebook SDK rather than Social Auth

For getting started working with Facebook sdk you need to create a project in facebook developer console kindly refer below link to [proceed](http://www.learn2crack.com/2015/06/android-facebook-sdk-prerequisites.html).

One App is created download and import [latest facebook sdk](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/downloads) in to your project

After import set facebook sdk as a library project to your eclipse

add below code in your mainfestifile application tag

```
 <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
```

where facebook_app_id is app id generated while creating a project in developer console

dont forget to include internet permissions

then add the following code in your Activity

//variables need to be declared

```
 CallbackManager callbackManager;
    ShareDialog shareDialog;
```

//in activity oncreate

```
FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
     callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
     shareDialog = new ShareDialog(this);
```

//For example sharing add the below snippet in on click lister of the button

```
ShareLinkContent content = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
                .setContentUrl(Uri.parse(copyTextToClipBoard()))
                .build();

                shareDialog.show(content);
```

Comment: Thanks for well described answer @venkatesh !! Let me look into it :)

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at my answer here:

- [Error Invalid Scopes: offline_access, publish_stream, when I try to connect with Facebook API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30074899/error-invalid-scopes-offline-access-publish-stream-when-i-try-to-connect-wi/30075426#30075426)

You should update to the most recent version 4.7 (https://code.google.com/p/socialauth/) and test again. I suspect that the permission set are set somewhere in the code as well.

> **Whats new in Version 4.7 ?**
>   ...
>   *Facebook API v2.2 updated*
>   ...

Comment: which social auth files i need to keep in my project @Tobi

Comment: what ever you given that social auth sdk is for Java not for Android

Comment: I don't really understand why you don't use the Facebook Android SDK anyway. The last update of https://code.google.com/p/socialauth-android/ is 2 years old.

Comment: Actually i did this project long time ago with social auth android adapter. now i am facing this problem. so now i will look into your suggestion @Tobi.

Answer (score 0):

I've looked through the [Socialauth sources](https://github.com/3pillarlabs/socialauth) and I see that you've made a slight error in your properties file. Custom permissions property should  be named as

```
graph.facebook.com.custom_permissions
```

not the

```
graph.facebook.com.custom_permission
```

(note the `s` on the end). I've tried it in my project and it works w/o any issues.

Comment: is there a way to fix this ?

Comment: @SWAppDev sorry, don't understand your question. What do you want to fix?

Comment: i'm getting this error while using socialauth "Invalid Scopes: read_stream." and i'm wondering how i can fix it

Comment: @SWAppDev add your set of permissions to the `graph.facebook.com.custom_permissions` property, excluding 'read_stream' permission.