# Facing permission Issues in facebook login integration using social auth in android

Tags: android, socialauth

Hi all I'm using SocialAuth library for Facebook integration in my app but after providing the credentials the screen attached below appears. Please help. 
[image]

Comment: this is best site to integrate social auth  sdk..http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/457153/How-to-integrate-Facebook-Twitter-Linkedin-in-Andr

Comment: you must get the Key and secrets from the facebook. Then only you will get facebook login page..!!

Comment: I have app id and secrets.. i exactly don't know how to add that but I tried it  
'adapter.addConfig(SocialAuthAdapter.Provider.FACEBOOK,"1024126224306394","d3c7cb3449569e57087a08645b293d39",null);'

Comment: Where did u add ID and secret key?? You have add it in "oauth_consumer.properties" file which is created in assets.

Comment: add your ID and secret keys like this:   #facebook
graph.facebook.com.consumer_key = YOUR_ID
graph.facebook.com.consumer_secret = YOUR_SECRET_KEY

Answer (score 2):

Add create Facebook ID and SECRET KEY like following.

Create oauth_consumer.properties in asset folder. Then copy ID and secret key into it.

**assets/oauth_consumer.properties**

```
 #facebook 
 graph.facebook.com.consumer_key = YOUR_ID                     
 graph.facebook.com.consumer_secret = YOUR_SECRET_KEY
```

Comment: Thanks for the response i've overcome the previous problems now facing problem with linked in integration

Comment: that part is also done.. but again stuck at fetching user profile data.. Shall i leave the socialAuth and use native Facebook/LinkedIn SDk?

Comment: You can easy get the user profile using socialAuth sdk. Once read the sample documentation of that given link.

Comment: yeah i'm trying that but those functions aren't working on my end

Comment: Once refer this link:   http://www.3pillarglobal.com/insights/part-1-using-socialauth-to-integrate-facebook-api-in-android ...it will give you full clarity.

Comment: now i've created a demo app for testing social auth.. here all the functions are working but not able to return the  required result.

Comment: Yeah..first i'm logged in successfully and then flow moves to error part when i try to fetch profile details

Comment: Once try to uncheck publish_stream option on facebook.

Comment: I dint get that.. how to do that

Comment: Refer this answer..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30522836/error-social-auth-4-4-invalid-scopes-publish-stream

Answer (score 1):

error is showing is invalid scopes publish_stream.

The permissions offline_access and publish_stream are deprecated, thus cannot be requested anymore.

publish_stream can be replaced by publish_actions, offline_access is gone.

Follow the link [Error Invalid Scopes: offline_access, publish_stream, when I try to connect with Facebook API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30074899/error-invalid-scopes-offline-access-publish-stream-when-i-try-to-connect-with)

I suggest not using old online tutorials use the Facebook docs first.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

Hope this will help.Good Luck

Comment: thanx for the response but I guess in the link the person was using facebook sdk , i don't know how to apply those things for socailauth

Comment: can you plz add the link

Comment: link ? for what , i dint get u