# PHPfox Facebook Connect Account Issues

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, phpfox

I have an issue with my PHPfox website regarding with Facebook Connect.

I recently enabled Facebook Connect to allow users to logged-in using their Facebook account. Already created our own Facebook App and followed all the steps mention here: [Error Invalid Scopes: offline_access, publish_stream, when I try to connect with Facebook API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30074899/error-invalid-scopes-offline-access-publish-stream-when-i-try-to-connect-with) - bugs fix for publish_stream permission issue.

But upon testing the button then clicking the first option (Yes, sync both accounts), I was always redirected to these the same page. My website also redirect to these page even if a certain Facebook user doesn't have an account on our website.

**Facebook Connect Page**:

> Facebook Connect Account Issues
>
> We already have an account created with us with the same email you
> have on Facebook. Would you like to sync both accounts? Note that if
> you sync both accounts you will not be able to use the original
> account here other then logging in with Facebook Connect.
>
> Yes, syncboth accounts.
>
> No, do not sync both accounts

PHPFox version - Core Version: 3.7.7(build 2)

Any ideas why this is happening?

Thanks a lot guys!