# Invalid Scopes: publish_actions, manage_pages, publish_pages, user_managed_groups, user_posts, user_photos

Tags: wordpress, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I got this error when I try to connect my wordpress site with Facebook API using SNAP auto Poster plugin.

> Invalid Scopes: publish_actions, manage_pages, publish_pages,
>   user_managed_groups, user_posts, user_photos. This message is only
>   shown to developers. Users of your app will ignore these permissions
>   if present. Please read the documentation for valid permissions at:
>   https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions

I already read [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30074899/error-invalid-scopes-offline-access-publish-stream-when-i-try-to-connect-with) in stackoverflow. And read [this article](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v3.0) in facebook about login permission. But still not find a clue on how to solve this.

I've also tried to remove the scopes one by one, but still facebook gives that error message.

Answer (score 5):

The publish_actions permission has been removed. Apps that have already been approved for publish_actions can continue using the permission until August 1st, 2018. If you want to provide a way for your app users to share content to Facebook and Instagram beyond this date, we encourage you to use our Sharing products instead.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/breaking-changes#4-24-2018

Comment: I already try removing `publish_actions`, but still get that errors.

Comment: I already have the permission in my app, but I still get error that I don't have the permission when I try to login with facebook. what could be the reason @NeelkanthVyas?

Comment: dude the permissions are already deprecated please check the link:  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/breaking-changes#4-24-2018